# Why may a mongoose document not get saved?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been using the following middleware for sometime, then suddenly it stops saving new docs. Further explanation in the comments

```
var body = req.body;

new ordersModel (body).save(function(err, newOrder, rowCount) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(rowCount) // logs 1

    updateEstimatedTime(newOrder); /* updateEstimatedTime runs but inside
   it, trying to find this document newOrder returns null,
   meaning it was never saved */
});
```

If I try something like

```
var pleaseWork = new ordersModel (body);
console.log(pleaseWork) // it dumps a loaded mongoose object
pleaseWork.save(function(err, newOrder, rowCount) {
```

So why doesn't it get persisted? I also tried reloading the server several times with this at the top just in case I was getting collections loaded during server setup

```
ordersModel.find({}, 'customer', function (err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs)
})
```

But it just returns the documents that existed before this fault began. I've triple checked the model name, it's the same all over the script. What could the code be lacking?
I have seen some examples online also that suggested something in the region of

```
var pleaseWork = new ordersModel ();
pleaseWork.foo = body.foo;
pleaseWork.bar = body.bar;
pleaseWork.john = body.john;

console.log(pleaseWork) // dumps a loaded mongoose object
pleaseWork.save(function(err, newOrder, rowCount) {
```

Now, this is not feasible for me; the ordersModel table has more than 10 columns-- dropping the body object in the model's constructor is sane enough and worked the last time the program was run.

Although I don't think it's necessary but if you need to see my model, I can make that available. Also the full server code in case you need to deploy and test.

Comment: `mongoose.set('debug', true);` And look at what is happening when your `.save()` is executing.

Comment: If it's in mongo it's not a table, it's a collection. And it's not a column, but rather a document property, since is a document oriented database not a relational database.

Comment: @NeilLunn should this come before the mongoose.createConnection assignment or am I free to place it anywhere?

Comment: Anywhere really, but preferably at the start. But are you calling `.createConnection()` or just `.connect()`? There "might" be an issue if you are using `.createConnection()` in the context of callbacks. Generally most mongoose methods do a "check" to see if the connection is present before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @NeilLunn's comment and my subsequent [debug data](https://pastebin.com/TMAAjWMh) I noticed on line 10 that I was removing documents with `estimatedDeliveryTime = null` which would include this new order. This line wasn't in the middleware but in a proxy initializing server variables

```
ordersModel.remove({estimatedDeliveryTime: null}).exec()
```

I was/am using it to cleanse the collection from invalid orders

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for coming back and explaining the source of the problem at least.